# Issue with spooling French text from Unix

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

We are spooling the data like shown below which consists of French text retrieved from a query into a text file from a `.sql` file, and we are executing that `.sql` file from Unix.

Strangely when we execute that `.sql` file from my colleague's machine connecting to the same Unix server with the same credentials the French text(with all the special characters) is being spooled, however it is not happening (all the special characters disappear) from any other machine (same Unix server with the same credentials).

```
SET ARRAY 4000
SET TERM OFF
SET WRAP OFF
SET FLUSH OFF
SET TAB OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TAB OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1999
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON

SPOOL %path%

SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE;

SPOOL OFF
```

I don't see any difference.

Please let me know what I need to check to make sure it works from every machine, or any thing I can do to get those special characters while spooling.

Comment: How are you seeing the difference - those users viewing the files they created, or looking at each others, or looking at hex dumps? Or are they being transferred elsewhere to be viewed? Are all the users connecting using the same OS language/locale, character set, terminal emulator CS translation. etc.? (If all are connecting to the same Unix account then presumably at that point NLS_LANG and other environment variables are the same, but perhaps verify that too...)

Comment: `%path%` looks like Windows rather than Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the encoding of your terminal with `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`

Then set your `NLS_LANG` accordingly before you run sqlplus, e.g.

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
$ export NLS_LANG
$ sqlplus ...
```

Comment: Hi Domscheit/Alex- Thank you for your time and responses. Looks like my colleague has set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 in that particular session while doing some testing, which created some confusion, the above has worked for me. Thank you, Pradeep